# kinetic smach_viewer or alternatives

Tags: smach

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I tried the tutorial with smach and saw that the smach_viewer isn't supported on ros kinetic.

Is smach still used in some projects or is there another solution for state machines in ROS kinetic ?

thanks for your help

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/239707/kinetic-smach_viewer-or-alternatives/) by [Hunk](https://answers.ros.org/users/3946/hunk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 222 on 2016-07-18

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found a way to make rqt_smach (which kind of is smach_viewer) work in kinetic - see my [gist on Github](https://gist.github.com/matt3o/88bced95dba37a8932a51904d0734dff) for more information.

---

Originally posted by [Matthias Hadlich](https://answers.ros.org/users/24950/matthias-hadlich/) with karma: 70 on 2017-03-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1